# Python challenge:zombies

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, if-statement, while-loop

I am trying to solve the following challenge, but to no avail:
The zombies start at range metres, and move at 0.5 metres per second. Each second, you first shoot one zombie, and then the remaining zombies shamble forwards another 0.5 metres.

If any zombies manage to get to 0 metres, you get eaten. If you run out of ammo before shooting all the zombies, you'll also get eaten. To keep things simple, we can ignore any time spent reloading.

Write a function that accepts the total number of zombies, a range in metres, and the number of bullets you have.

If you shoot all the zombies, return "You shot all X zombies." If you get eaten before killing all the zombies, and before running out of ammo, return "You shot X zombies before being eaten: overwhelmed." If you run out of ammo before shooting all the zombies, return "You shot X zombies before being eaten: ran out of ammo."

(If you run out of ammo at the same time as the remaining zombies reach you, return "You shot X zombies before being eaten: overwhelmed.".)

My code thus far is:

```
def zombie_shootout(zombies, distance, ammo):
    if ammo >= zombies:
        ammo -= 1
        zombies -= 1
        distance -= 0.5
    elif ammo < zombies:
        print("You shot ",zombies,"zombies before being eaten: ran out of ammo.")
    elif distance == 0:
        print("You shot ",zombies,"zombies before being eaten: overwhelmed.")
    else:
        print("You shot all ", zombies,"zombies.")
```

I know there are solutions for those who can't solve this puzzle, but they are most likely much more succinct and elegant, and I would like to know how (if it is possible at all) to go about doing it with my way (lots of ifs and elifs and maybe add a while somewhere).

Comment: Do you know what a `while` loop is? (this may sound snarky, but it's meant sincerely, I promise)

Comment: Hahah yeah kinda, I wanted to put "while distance>0", but that wouldn't work in this case, and I am not sure how to keep iterating through my program (maybe "for i in range(distance)"?).

Comment: You're close. Why do you think `while distance > 0` does not work?

Comment: I should add, as a new programmer you might be interested in learning about rubber duck programming https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging I think it could help solve your problem here

Comment: Am I missing something? This puzzle doesn’t need a loop or anything of the sort. It’s straightforward arithmetic: `return ammo >= zombies and distance_in_metres > zombies * 0.5`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go through your code: you've said in the comments that you know you need a `while` loop somewhere, so let's think about what condition we should put on that loop. We want to keep shooting until we either run out of ammo, the zombies eat us, or we run out of zombies. We can do this using `all()`, to check that all of the variables are greater than 0:

```
while all(x > 0 for x in (distance, ammo, zombies)):
```

This is equivalent to:

```
while distance>0 and ammo>0 and zombies>0:
```

While this condition is `True`, we want to apply the logic in your question, which you already had in your if statement. You also want to print the amount of zombies that were shot, so let's add a `zombies_shot` variable, and set it to `0` at the start of the function, and increment it every time we run our `while` loop. We now have:

```
def zombie_shootout(zombies, distance, ammo):
    zombies_shot = 0
    while all(x>0 for x in (distance, ammo, zombies)):
        ammo -= 1
        zombies_shot += 1
        zombies -= 1
        distance -= 0.5
```

So now we need to check the conditions after we've broken out of the `while` loop. You almost had this as well, but let's also check that there are still zombies remaining, otherwise if we shoot the last zombie just before it reaches us, for example, your function will still say that we got eaten. We can also use the new `zombies_shot` variable.

```
if ammo <= 0 and zombies > 0:
    print("You shot",zombies_shot,"zombies before being eaten: ran out of ammo.")
elif distance <= 0 and zombies > 0:
    print("You shot",zombies_shot,"zombies before being eaten: overwhelmed.")
else:
    print("You shot all", zombies_shot,"zombies.")
```

We could also add `return` statements instead of `print` statements, but that's up to you. Our full function is now:

```
def zombie_shootout(zombies, distance, ammo):
    zombies_shot = 0
    while all(x>0 for x in (distance, ammo, zombies)):
        ammo -= 1
        zombies_shot += 1
        zombies -= 1
        distance -= 0.5
    if ammo <= 0 and zombies > 0:
        print("You shot",zombies_shot,"zombies before being eaten: ran out of ammo.")
    elif distance <= 0 and zombies > 0:
        print("You shot",zombies_shot,"zombies before being eaten: overwhelmed.")
    else:
        print("You shot all", zombies_shot,"zombies.")
```

Comment: @Nathan fair enough, added clarification :)

Comment: As noted in my comment below the answer, I don’t see why a loop is used.

Comment: @KonradRudolph obviously this problem could be solved with a simple calculation - I presume the intention of this exercise is to teach basic loops and functions, and OP acknowledges this at the end of his question.

Comment: @CDJB just one more question - it turns out return does in fact have to be used, but how do I make it so return's output is completely identical to print? Currently return returns "('You shot all', 3, 'zombies.')", but it has to be 'You shot all 3 zombies.', without parenthesis or commas. I tried editing it, but couldn't work it out.

Comment: @JohnDoe Use something like: return 'You shot ' + zombies_shot + ' zombies' . If you're using Python 3.6+, you could also use return f'You shot {zombies_shot} zombies' using f-strings :)

Comment: Yeah yeah, I figured it out eventually yesterday. :) Thank you so much for your help! F-strings are amazing, old python was so much more unnecessarily complex(%-formatting and str.format()).

Answer (score 2):

While @CDJB 's answer is really good, I'd like to point out another approach that also works but is slightly faster (computationally speaking). The reason that this might be important is that if the entire world gets bit, you have ~7.000.000.000 zombies to deal with, so a while loop would take very long.

We know the zombies start at a distance `x` m, and we can shoot 1 zombie for every 0.5 m travelled. This means we can shoot:

```
 zombies_shot_distance = int(distance * 2)
```

We also know we cannot shoot more zombies than we have ammo, so:

```
 zombies_shot_ammo = ammo
```

The maximum number of zombies shot is the lowest of the two:

```
 zombies_shot_max = min(zombies_shot_distance, zombies_shot_ammo)
```

If the maximum amount of zombies shot is lower than the amount of zombies, we know we won't be able to shoot all the zombies:

```
if zombies > zombies_shot_max:
    print("You shot", zombies_shot_max, "zombies")
    if zombies_shot_ammo <= zombies_shot_distance:
         print("because you ran out of ammo")
    else:
         print("because you were overwhelmed")
else:
    print("You shot all the zombies")
```

Comment: Thank you, always good to know the different ways to approach a problem!

Answer (score 2):

There is a short recursive solution, but since you want to track the number of zombies shot, we need to write a recursive helper that keeps track of this number.

```
def zombie_rec(zombies, distance, ammo, shot):
    if zombies <= 0:
        return f"You shot all {shot} zombies."
    elif ammo <= 0:
        return f"You shot {shot} zombies before being eaten: ran out of ammo."
    elif distance <= 0:
        return f"You shot {shot} zombies before being eaten: overwhelmed."

    else:
        return zombie_rec(zombies - 1, distance - 0.5, ammo - 1, shot + 1)

def zombie(zombies, distance, ammo):
    print(zombie_rec(zombies, distance, ammo, 0))
```

Since recursion can be mind bending, let's go through this step by step.

The first law of recursion is to check your end conditions first.  In this case, we have three.

1. All zombies are dead and we win.
2. Distance is zero and we get eaten (now).
3. Ammo is zero and we get eaten (eventually).

Note that we should check them in this order, as `zombies == 0` means we live even if the other two are also 0.

If none of the following conditions are true, then we must go one more turn.  This can be accomplished with a recursive call, noting that

1. `zombies` and `ammo` all decreased by 1 and `distance` by 0.5.  (As we shot a zombie and while the remainder advanced).
2. We increment `shot` by 1 to track the number shot at the end of this round.

Similar to `while` loops, we should double check that we are gaurenteed to complete and not end up in a infinite loop.  In this case, we are sure to that either `zombies`, `distance`, or `ammo` will reach zero as they all decrease by 1 each step.

On second thought, switching the three end conditions to `<=` will make this more robust to bad arguments (negatives or fractional values).

If you are interested in learning more about recursion, I strongly suggest [The Little Schemer](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/BTLS/)

Comment: I like this example of a recursive function. Could you explain how these work so that it's clear for @John Doe as well?

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work on the website, but I tried it in an ide with the same parameters and it works fine, thank you!

Comment: Worked with return(last line), thank you very much!